# how to get dates fiter wise get product collection in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

shopify backend site created my custom meta field and that name is a start date and end date. when i click both fields. then get product collection date-wise. so please help me with how it works.

get product collection start and end date meta using a filter.